# Unableto load library 'c': The specified module could not be found

Tags: java, windows, yajsw

I am trying to run a java application as a windows service using yajsw-stable-11.11 wrapper.

I am using below combination[1], but getting exception[2] while same wrapper.conf is working in another identical windows instance where I am using the same versions as below. Please help.

[1]

yajsw-stable-11.11

jdk1.7.0_51

Windows Server 2012/6.2/amd64

[2]

```
INFO|-1/0|"Test Server"|16-09-01 15:25:59| gobler terminated OUTPUT -1 java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO|-1/0|"Test Server"|16-09-01 15:25:59|gobler terminated OUTPUT -1Exception in thread "yajsw.controller-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unableto load library 'c': The specified module could not be found. 
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:169) 
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:242) 
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140) 
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:368) 
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:353) 
at org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixProcess$CLibrary.<clinit>(PosixProcess.java:60) 
at org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixProcess.destroy(PosixProcess.java:558) 
at org.rzo.yajsw.wrapper.AbstractWrappedProcess.stopOsProcess(AbstractWrappedProcess.java:2082) 
at org.rzo.yajsw.wrapper.AbstractWrappedProcess.stopInternal(AbstractWrappedProcess.java:1996) 
at org.rzo.yajsw.wrapper.AbstractWrappedProcess.restartInternal(AbstractWrappedProcess.java:2550) 
at org.rzo.yajsw.wrapper.WrappedJavaProcess$2.fire(WrappedJavaProcess.java:557) 
at org.rzo.yajsw.controller.AbstractController.handleListeners(AbstractController.java:108) 
at org.rzo.yajsw.controller.AbstractController.setState(AbstractController.java:146) 
at org.rzo.yajsw.controller.jvm.JVMController$4$1.run(JVMController.java:701) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
INFO|-1/0|"Test Server"|16-09-01 15:25:59| gobler terminated ERROR -1 java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO|-1/0|"Test Server"|16-09-01 15:25:59|gobler terminated ERROR -1
```

Comment: That code is probably trying to load the standard C library, which is called `libc.so` on Linux / Unix-like operating systems (that's where the "c" comes from). It does not exist on Windows in the same way. This code is probably written in such a way that it only works on Linux or other Unix-like OSes and not on Windows. Or it thinks it is running on Linux instead of Windows.